# Flutter - get value in ListView text to paste on TextField on another dart file

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

[main.dart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADdHQ.jpg)
[homeview.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaU0a.jpg)

I have a problem I have 2 different dart files, main.dart and homeview.dart here I deliberately made a custom dialog at homeview.dart, the dialog contains listview and only data strings, I want to make it and on the item list I create an Inkwell widget to be able to OnTap :, and in main.dart it contains TextFormField,

The question is how when in the onTap list item, the text string moves to TextFormField on main.dart?

homeview.dart

```
final List<String> _listViewTypeInvest = [
  "12 Months Invest",
  "18 Months Invest",
  "24 Months Invest",
];



child: ListView(
  children: _listViewTypeInvest
      .map( (data) => ListTile(
            title: Text(data),
            onTap: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text(
                    "$data Clicked!",
                    style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
                  ),
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                )),
          ))
      .toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a `Function` callback.
So in your `homeview.dart` you want to add a Function as a property.

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {

  final void Function(String) onStringSelected;

  const HomeView({Key key, @required this.onStringSelected}) : super(key: key);

  ...
```

Now you can call this function once the user presses a button in your dialog.
So this will be your `onTap()` function:

```
onTap: () {
  onStringSelected(data); // this fires the callback function
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text(
      "$data Clicked!",
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Montserrat"),
    ),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  ));
}),
```

Where ever you instantiate the `homeview.dart` file you can now listen for that new `onStringSelected` function callback and for example set the text property of your TextFormField.

```
HomeView(
  onStringSelected: (myDataString) {
    print("The user clicked $myDataString");
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, but how to define onStringSelected(data); ?

Comment: do I mean in "another file dart"?

Comment: onStringSelected is defined in your Homeview.dart. Its a property. Somewhere you instantiate the HomeView() Widget. You now simply pass a function for the onStringSelected property.

Comment: Please share more code. Especially the homeview.dart and the file where you use the HomeView() widget.